# Помогите найти ошибки в коде javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, рефакторинг

```js
class dateInput {
  constructor() {
    this.input = document.querySelector(".input");

    this.input.onChange = this.onChange;
  }

  onChange(event) {
    this.inputValue = event.srcElement.value;
    this.updateTime = new Date();
    return this.inputValue;
  }
}

class dateRange extends dataInput {
  constructor() {
    this.container = document.querySelector('.containerForLastUpdateRecordAndPeriodItems')
  }

  createItems(period) {
    let dates = [];
    for (i = +period.start; i < +period.end; i += 3600000 * 168)
      dates.push(i)
    let periods = [];
    for (i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
      let date = new Date(dates[i]);
      if (date.getDay() == 1) period = `${date.toLocaleDateString()} - {date.setHours(168).toLocaleDateString()}`
      else if (date.getDay() == 2) period[i] = `${date.setHours(-24).toLocaleDateString()} - {date.setHours(144).toLocaleDateString()}`
      else if (date.getDay() == 3) period[i] = `${date.setHours(-48).toLocaleDateString()} - {date.setHours(120).toLocaleDateString()}`
      else if (date.getDay() == 4) period[i] = `${date.setHours(-48).toLocaleDateString()} - {date.setHours(120).toLocaleDateString()}`
      else if (date.getDay() == 5) period[i] = `${date.setHours(-72).toLocaleDateString()} - {date.setHours(96).toLocaleDateString()}`
      else if (date.getDay() == 6) period[i] = `${date.setHours(-96).toLocaleDateString()} - {date.setHours(72).toLocaleDateString()}`
      else if (date.getDay() == 0) period[i] = `${date.setHours(-120).toLocaleDateString()} - {date.setHours(48).toLocaleDateString()}`

      var n = periods.length,
        a = periods.length;
      do {
        b = false;
        a /= 1.3;
        if (a == 9 || a == 10) a = 11;
        if (a < 1) a = 1;
        for (const i = 0; i < n - a; ++i) {
          if (periods[i] > periods[i + a]) {
            b = true;
            var t = periods[i + a];
            periods[i + a] = periods[i];
            periods[i] = t;
          }
        }
      } while (a > 1 || b);
    }
    return periods;
  }

  renderItems(items) {
    this.container.appendChild(element = document.createElement('div'))
    element.innerText = `Последнее изменение: ${this.updateTime.getDate() + '.' + this.updateTime.getMonth() > 9 ? : '0'+this.updateTime.getMonth() : this.updateTime.getMonth()}`

    items.forEach(function(item) {
        const element = document.createElement('div', {
          innerText: item
        });
        this.container.appendChild(element)
      }
    }

    onChange() {   renderItems(this.createItems(this.createPeriod(this.inputValue)));
    }

    createPeriod(date) {
      let newDate = date;
      newDate.year = newDate.year + 1;
      return {
        start: date,
        end: newDate
      }
    }
  }

  const range = Object.create(dateRange.prototype);
  range.constructor = range.constructor.bind(range);
  range.constructor();
```

```html
<div class="input"><input type='date' /></div>
<div class="containerForLastUpdateRecordAndPeriodItems"></div>
```

Comment: Задайте вопрос конкретнее. Что Вы пытаетесь сделать? Что не получается?

Comment: Рефакторить надо рабочий код, а не код с ошибками, как в данном случае